# React native, choppy independent parallel animations?

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, reactjs, react-native

I have a couple of different animated components in the same View. The components do not know about each other, but their animations happens simultaneously.

Occasionally, but not always, one of the animations will start dropping frames, or it wont start for X seconds.

Is there some better way to handle this situation that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for now, is just wrapping the more important animation in, requestAnimationFrame(() => { - animation cb here - });

its referenced in the performance docs for react native, but it infers that a TimerMixin is needed, which doesn't appear to be the case. (so, even though the docs say to use this.requestAnimationFrame, you don't need "this.").